# Either correct VB6/DOS/SQL function or suggest better alternative

Tags: sql, vb6, dos

I am currently reprogramming code made long ago by a less than skilled programmer. Granted the code works, and has for a number of years but it is not very efficient.

The code in question is in VB6 with SQL calls and it checks a particular directory on the drive (in this example we will use c:\files) and if a file exists, it moves the file to the processing directory loads the parameters for that particular file and processes them accordingly.

Currently the code uses the DIR function in VB6 to identify a file in the appropriate directory. The only problem is that if a number of files exist in the directory it is a crap shoot as to if it will grab the 5kb file and process it in 3 seconds or if it will grab the 500,000kb file and not process any others for the next 10 minutes.

I search many message boards to find some way to have it pick the smallest file and found I could build a complicated array to perform something similar to a sort but I decided to try alternate ideas instead to hopefully reduce processing time involved. Using ancient DOS knowledge I created something that should work, but for some reason is not (hence posting here).

I made a batch file that we will call c:\test.bat which contained the following lines:

```
delete c:\test.txt
dir /OS /B c:\files\*.txt>c:\test.txt
```

This deletes a prior existence of test.txt the pipes a directory without headers sorted by file size smallest to largest into c:\test.txt.

I then inserted the following code into the pre-existing code at the beginning:

```
Shell "c:\test.bat", vbHide
filepath = "c:\test.txt"
Open filepath For Input As #1
Input #1, filegrabber
Close #1
```

When I step through the code I can see that this works correctly, except now later on in the code I get a

Runtime error 91 Object variable or with block variable not set

in regard to assigning a FileSystemObject. Am I correct in guessing that FSO and Shell do not work well together? Also if you can suggest a better alternative to getting the smallest file from a existing directory suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for sorting.

Just use `Dir()` to cruise through the directory.  Before the loop set a `Smallest` Long variable to `&H7FFFFFFF` then inside the loop test each returned file name using the `FileLen()` function.

If `FileLen()` returns a value less than `Smallest` assign that size to `Smallest` and assign that file name to `SmallestFile` a String variable.

Upon loop exit if `Smallest = &H7FFFFFFF` there were no files, otherwise `SmallestFile` has your file name.

Seems incredibly simple, what am I missing?

Comment: And here I thought I had looked at it from every angle. Not only does it work, it does it far better than what I was trying and it doesn't throw errors from previously working areas. Thank you kind sir.

Comment: Glad it was helpful.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the FileSystemObject's Files collection.  Just iterate the files collection for a given folder and evaluate each File object's Size property.  So long as you don't have a million files in a folder or something, performance should be fine.